# Windows 10 update service is disabled automatically after update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-services

After a successful update, **Windows 10 Update Service** is often set to **"disabled"** and I have to re-enable it manually.

- There is no third-party software installed on the system
- No task schedule is created
- I Created a software restriction policy in order to assure nothing interferes with the service.

But still, the service is often set to **"disabled"** after updates!

I think it has to do with **DonotSPY10** since I'm using it, Windows is acting weirdly and re-enables what I disable in settings after updates and sometimes shutdown!

Comment: If you suspect DoNotSPY10 is at fault, reverse all changes it made to your system, and uninstall it.  You can then, verify the behavior still happens, and if it does reinstall it knowing it isn't at fault.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Yes, I've found that DoNotSPY10 and other similar software turn off some windows update future including: the automatic drivers, apps and peer-to-peer updates of which Windows 10 responses sometimes or somehow fails to start the update service and after a successful update, it seems windows is reverting some changes that conflicts with other settings set previously in Group Policy, ultimately, the service is set to disabled or sometimes the update doesn't work with a nice error message! Guess it's not a good idea to use those anti-spy and set everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

Run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth command to repair system components.

Run Windows Update troubleshooter.

Change the Windows Update service startup type as Manual, stop then start it.

Clean boot computer and monitor

Comment: I don't think it has to do with corrupted files because I have experienced this issue in over 3 different PCs running Windows 10 Pro. Rather, I think there is some mis-configuration in Windows 10 that I missed, or I just don't know what causes this issue!

Comment: @ArchCapital, if you have seen this happen on three different Windows 10 Pro computers, there is definitely something "different" about your configuration.  The normal state of the Windows Update service should be `Manual (Trigger Start)`.  If it isn't, something or someone changed within the operating system to cause that service to become disabled.

Comment: I think it has to do with DonotSPY10 since I'm using it, Windows is acting weirdly and re-enables what I disable in settings after updates and sometimes shutdown!

Comment: This isn't the first time I have seen a question posted within the Super User realm from people having problems with DonotSPY10.  To be perfectly honest, it seems like it is more trouble than it's worth.  In contrast, I adjust my Windows 10 privacy settings utilizing the built-in tools, and everything works perfectly.  Anything beyond that seems to do more harm than good.

Comment: There are better alternatives than DoNotSPY10.  You should use those, but my suggestion is use none of them, since they all perform actions that intestinally do something to break how Windows behaves.  The only safe way to do anything is through a registry key or group policy

Comment: @Run5k Thanks, I guess I should stick to windows settings.